# Partition function of an entropic spring

Tags: statistical-mechanics, biophysics, partition-function

I am looking at the derivation of partition function of a freely-jointed-chain: http://biologicalphysics.iop.org/cws/article/lectures/48662

The chain looks something like this:

[image]

I need the energy of a general configuration to find the partition function. In the derivation, they write down the energy of a configuration as: $$ E = -f b\sum cos(\theta_i)$$
I don't understand where this come from or what $\theta_i$ is in the derivation. I think it's the angle that chain elements make with each other. Then my guess is that they are basically saying that work done by the force is displacement dotted with force. I have some issues with that:

- Why minus sign?
- Why are they assuming the force is constant?
- What is the direction of the force and why is theta the angle that force makes with displacement?
- I can't quite visualize what is going on there.

Comment: 1) You want the energy to be minimal if the polymer stretches in the direction of the force. 2) Why not? 3) The direction is arbitrary. The term $\cos\theta$ comes from the scalar product between the force and the position of the free end of the polymer, at which the force is applied (assume, for example, that the other end is kept fixed in space).

Comment: @YvanVelenik I understand what you mean by "why not", but this is exactly my problem with it. I can't quite imagine what it looks like and what is the argument here and what is the energy of a chain under tension

Comment: It is really a form of equivalence of ensembles. On the one hand, you can consider an ensemble with both endpoints of the polymer fixed and compute the force acting on the fixed endpoints. But, you may also (and this is what seems to be done here) apply a constant force on one endpoint (say, keeping the other fixed), and study the resulting position of the free endpoint. These two points of view will ultimately be equivalent. This is analogous to choosing between a canonical or grand canonical formulation when analyzing a gas.